# getting the value of child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get the value of child component yet not successful. Here what I am working on ...

```
import React from "react";
import Tooltip from "rc-tooltip";
import Slider, { Range } from "rc-slider";

const Handle = Slider.Handle;

const handle = props => {
   const { value, dragging, index, ...restProps } = props;
   return (
      <Tooltip
         prefixCls="rc-slider-tooltip"
         overlay={value}
         visible={dragging}
         placement="top"
         key={index}
      >
         <Handle value={value} {...restProps} />
      </Tooltip>
   );
};



const Slider = props => {



   return (
      <div>
         <div style={{ width: 300, margin: 30 }}>
            <p>{this.props.title}</p>
            <Slider min={0} max={10} defaultValue={5} handle={handle}/>
         </div>

      </div>
   );
};

export default Slider;
```

Main App.js

```
import Slider from '.....'

class App extends Component{
     constructor(props){
     super(props);

        this.state = {
              val: 0
        }

      } 

  render() {

   return(

     <Slider onChange={this.state.value} />
    )

}

}
```

I am looking to get the value to be updated to this App.js state as the slider is being dragged. onChange is not updating the state. How should I modify so that slider value gets updated on this.state.value.

Comment: you are not setting the state of parent component. It is always 0

Comment: Also, this.props.title is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Slider component from `rc-slider` has an `onChange` prop event which is a function. You need to pass this method to slider and update the state instead of just passing the state value

```
import React from "react";
import Tooltip from "rc-tooltip";
import Slider, { Range } from "rc-slider";

const Handle = Slider.Handle;

const handle = props => {
   const { value, dragging, index, ...restProps } = props;
   return (
      <Tooltip
         prefixCls="rc-slider-tooltip"
         overlay={value}
         visible={dragging}
         placement="top"
         key={index}
      >
         <Handle value={value} {...restProps} />
      </Tooltip>
   );
};



const Slider = props => {



   return (
      <div>
         <div style={{ width: 300, margin: 30 }}>
            <p>{this.props.title}</p>
            <Slider min={0} max={10} defaultValue={5} onChange={props.onChange} handle={handle}/>
         </div>

      </div>
   );
};

export default Slider;
```

---

```
class App extends Component{
     constructor(props){
     super(props);

        this.state = {
              val: 0
        }

      } 
  onChange=(value) => {
      this.setState({val: value});
  }
  render() {
     return(
       <Slider onChange={this.onChange} />
     )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Live code

https://codesandbox.io/s/n9y97y55kp

Let me know if you have any doubts

You just have to pass the event from child to parent component to update the values.

Answer (score 0):

according to rc-slider [document](https://github.com/schrodinger/rc-slider), you should **pass a function** to Slider onChange.

```
import Slider from '.....'

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      val: 0
    }

  }

  handleSliderChange = (value) => {
    console.log(value) // maybe a string or a object
    this.setState({val: value})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Slider onChange={this.handleSliderChange} />
    )
  }
}
```

above code should work